# How to mimic simple inheritance with base and child class constructors in Lua (Tutorial)

Tags: oop, inheritance, lua

How to mimic simple inheritance with parent and child class constructors in Lua?

*I will provide and accept and answer and would greatly appreciate if you commented on it or edited interesting information into it.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a guide for mimicking basic parent/child class inheritance in Lua.

---

I assume that basic features and syntax of Lua are known to the reader. The following statements are especially important:

- There are no classes or objects in Lua, just tables.
- A table can have a metatable.
- If the metatable `mt` of a table `t` contains the `__index` metamethod (thus `mt.__index`), access to a non-existent key in `t` is attempted to be resolved via what's assigned to `mt.__index`.
- If `t` calls a function `t.foo()` like this `t:foo()` then `t` itself is passed to `foo()` as the first argument called `self`. Inside the function, `t` itself is accessible as `self`.

---

## Base class

### Code

```
Base = {}
function Base:new(name)
    Base.__index = Base
    local obj = {}
    setmetatable(obj, Base)
    obj.name = name
    return obj
end

function Base:sayName() 
    print(self.name..": My name is "..self.name..".")
end
```

Because of what the function `Base:new(name)` does, `Base` can now be seen as a new class, with `Base:new(name)` being its **constructor**. Remember that `Base` really is a table that sits somewhere in memory, not some abstract "class blue print". It contains a function `Base:sayName()`. This is what we could call a **method** with respect to OOP lingo.

But how does `Base:new(name)` let `Base` act like a class?

### Explanation

```
Base.__index = Base
```

The `Base` table gets an `__index` metamethod, namely itself. Whenever `Base` is used as a metatable, searches to a non-existent index will be redirected to... `Base` itself. (Wait for it.) The line could also be written as `self.__index = self`, because `Base` calls `:new(name)` and thus `self` is `Base` therein. I prefer the first version, because it clearly shows what's happening. Also, `Base.__index = Base` could go outside of `Base:new(name)`, however, I prefer having all the "set up" happen inside one scope (the "constructor") for the sake of clarity.

```
local obj = {}
setmetatable(obj, Base)
```

`obj` is created as a new empty table. It will become what we think of as an **object** of the "class" `Base`. The `Base` is now the metatable of `obj`. Since `Base` has an `__index`, access to non-existent keys in `obj` well be redirected to what is assigned to `Base.__index`. And since `Base.__index` is `Base` itself, access to non-existent keys in `obj` will be redirected to `Base` (where it would find `Base:sayName()`, for instance)!

```
obj.name = name
return obj
```

The `obj` (!) gets a new entry, a **member**, to which the constructor parameter is assigned. The `obj` is then returned and is what we would interpret as an **object of class `Base`**.

### Demonstration

```
b = Base:new("Mr. Base")
b:sayName()
```

This prints *"Mr. Base: My name is Mr. Base."* as expected. `b` finds `sayName()` via the metatable-`__index` mechanism as described above, because it doesn't have such a key. `sayName()` lives inside `Base` (the "class table") and `name` inside `b` (the "object table").

## Child class

### Code

```
Child = {}
function Child:new(name, age) -- our child class takes a second argument
    Child.__index = Child
    setmetatable(Child, {__index = Base}) -- this is different!
    local obj = Base:new(name, age)       -- this is different!
    setmetatable(obj, Child)
    obj.age = age
    return obj
end

function Child:sayAge()
    print(self.name..": I am "..tonumber(self.age).." years old.")
end
```

The code is almost exactly the same as for the base class! Adding a second parameter in the `Child:new(name, age)` (i.e. the constructor) is not especially noteworthy. `Base` could also have had more than one parameter. However, the second and third line inside `Child:new(name, age)` were added and that is what causes `Child` to "**inherit**" from `Base.`

Note that `Base` may contain `Base.__index`, which makes it useful when used *as* a metatable, but that it *has* no metatable *itself*.

### Explanation

```
setmetatable(Child, {__index = Base})
```

In this line, we assign a metatable to the `Child` class table. This metatable contains an `__index` metamethod, which is set to the `Base` class table. Thus, the `Child` class table will try to resolve access to non-existent keys via the `Base` class table. Thus, the `Child` class table has access to all of its own and all of `Base`'s methods!

```
local obj = Base:new(name, age)
setmetatable(obj, Child)
```

In the first line, a new `Base` object table is created. At this point, its `__index` metamethod points to the `Base` class table. However, right in line two, its metatable is assigned to the `Child` class table. The reason why `obj` does not lose access to `Base` class methods lies in the fact that we redirected non-successful key accesses in `Child` to `Base` (by giving `Child` the proper metatable) just before! Since `obj` was created as a `Base` object table, it contains all of its members. Additionally, it also contains the members of a `Child` object table (once they are added in the `Child:new(name, age)` "constructor". It finds the methods of the `Child` class table via its own metamethod. And it finds the methods in the `Base` class table via the metamethod in the `Child` class table.

**Note:** With "`Base` object table" I mean the table that is returned by `Base:new(name)`. With "`Base` class table" I mean the actual `Base` table. Remember, there are no classes/objects in Lua! The `Base` class table and the `Base` object table *together* mimic what we think of as OOP behavior. The same goes for `Child`, of course.

**Also, scoping the assignment of `Child`'s metatable inside `Child:new(name, age)` allows us to call `Base`'s "constructor" and pass the `name` argument to it!**

### Demonstration

```
c = Child:new("Mrs. Child", 42)
c:sayName()
c:sayAge()
```

This prints *"Mrs. Child: My name is Mrs. Child."* and *"Mrs. Child: I am 42 years old."* as expected.

## Conclusion

The sections above described how to implement OOP behavior in Lua. It is important to understand that

- Base methods live inside the `Base` class table
- Base members live inside the `Base` object table returned by `Base:new()`
- Child methods live inside the `Child` class table
- Child members live inside the `Child` object table returned by `Child:new()`

Referencing the correct tables is accomplished by the table's metatables.

- All class tables assign themselves to their `__index` key. When used as metatables, they refer to themselves (i.e. where the class methods live). There is only one class table per "class".
- Base classes don't *have* a metatable. They *are used* as metatables.
- Child class tables also *have* a metatable, namely `{__index = Base}` (which redirects calls to the `Base` class table, i.e. where the `Base` class methods live).
- All object tables assign their corresponding class tables as metatables. Since the class tables have set their `__index` metamethod, calls to the object tables can be redirected to the class tables where the class methods live. If it is a child class table (which means it also has a metatable), the redirection can happen even further. There can be arbitrarily many object tables.

[image: Schematic table overview]

Use the image above to follow along: What happens if a `Child` object table `c` tries to access a `Base` method, e.g. `c:sayName()`? Well: Has `c` a `sayName()` key? No. Does it have a metatable? Yes: `Child` (the `Child` class table). Does `Child` have an `__index` metamethod? Yes. Where does it point? To `Child` itself. Does `Child` have a `sayName()` key? No. Does `Child` have a metatable? Yes. Does it have an `__index` metamethod? Yes. Where does it point? To the `Base` class table. Does it have a `sayName()` key? Yes! :-)

## Note

I am no Lua expert! I have only done some scripting in Lua so far, but over the last days I tried to wrap my mind around this. I found a lot of different, sometimes confusing solutions and finally arrived at this, which I would call the most simple but transparent solution. If you find any errors or caveats do not hesitate to comment!

Comment: what you call a _dunder_ is called a **metamethod** in Lua. So unless people come from the Python universe dunder will cause unnecessary confusion. you should restrict yourself to terms used in the Lua reference manual.

Comment: @Piglet Ahhh, thank you for that comment! You are absolutely right! This is definitely because I spent the last months digging into Python! I will change it when I do the other major edit I announced!

Comment: With this implementation, how can one check whether an instance of `Child` is also an instance of `Base`?

Comment: @Sobhan I asked myself this question as well, but haven't quite tried to find an answer... Without thinking it through at the moment, one could maybe create a "hidden" variable that stores the parent class name?